# Facebook Authentication failing

Tags: php, facebook, smarty, facebook-php-sdk

A member of a forum created an authentification system for my website allowing user to sign-in or sign-up 
on my website using facebook api (facebook sdk)

For an unknow reason (I must have screwed somewhere) the system stopped working and I cant connect.

Could you help me fixing the problem.

I'm using facebook-sdk php classes (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)
(files used are uploaded on pastebin because they are too long)

The facebook connexion windows is oppening and the url sent back seems to contain de information needed for the authentification (but no cookies of facebook are created (notshowing on chrome console))

so i think the problem must come from the config.php files
I'm using smarty as a template engine if that affects anything.

My website 
www.entendu.info

the login url : www.entendu.info/login

Thanks a lot

```
<?php

require_once ($config[basedir] . '/include/facebook_api/facebook.php');

if ($config['enable_fc'] == "1") {

    $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => '**APPID***', 'secret' => '***SECRETID***', ));
    $user = $facebook -> getUser();

    if ($user) {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook -> api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['fb_277467322296156_user_id'])) {

        $femail = $user_profile['email'];
        $fname = $user_profile['name'];
        $fname = htmlentities(strip_tags($fname), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        $femail = htmlentities(strip_tags($femail), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        $fsex = $user_profile['gender'];
        $fsex = htmlentities(strip_tags($fsex), ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        if ($fsex == "male") {
            $ag = "1";
        } else {
            $ag = "0";
        }

        $ffirstname = $user_profile['first_name'];
        $flastname = $user_profile['last_name'];

        $date = explode('/', $user_profile['birthday']);
        $fbirthday = $date[2] . "/" . $date[0] . "/" . $date[1];

        $fcity = $user_profile['hometown']['name'];

        $query = "SELECT USERID FROM members WHERE email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($femail) . "' limit 1";
        $executequery = $conn -> execute($query);
        $FUID = intval($executequery -> fields['USERID']);
        if ($FUID > 0) {
            $query = "SELECT USERID,email,username,verified,gender from members WHERE USERID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($FUID) . "' and status='1'";
            $result = $conn -> execute($query);
            if ($result -> recordcount() > 0) {
                $query = "update members set lastlogin='" . time() . "', lip='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "' WHERE USERID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($FUID) . "'";
                $conn -> execute($query);

                $_SESSION['USERID'] = $result -> fields['USERID'];
                $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $result -> fields['email'];
                $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $result -> fields['username'];
                $_SESSION['VERIFIED'] = $result -> fields['verified'];
                $_SESSION['GENDER'] = $result -> fields['gender'];
                $_SESSION['FB'] = "1";

            }
        } else {
            $md5pass = md5(generateCode(5) . time());

            if ($fname != "" && $femail != "") {

                $query = "INSERT INTO members SET email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($femail) . "',birthday='" . mysql_real_escape_string($fbirthday) . "',city='" . mysql_real_escape_string($fcity) . "',username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($fname) . "',firstname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($ffirstname) . "',lastname='" . mysql_real_escape_string($flastname) . "', password='" . mysql_real_escape_string($md5pass) . "', addtime='" . time() . "', lastlogin='" . time() . "', ip='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', lip='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', verified='1', gender='" . $ag . "'";
                $result = $conn -> execute($query);
                $userid = mysql_insert_id();
                if ($userid != "" && is_numeric($userid) && $userid > 0) {

                    $query = "SELECT USERID,email,username,verified,gender from members WHERE USERID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($userid) . "'";
                    $result = $conn -> execute($query);

                    $_SESSION['USERID'] = $result -> fields['USERID'];
                    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $result -> fields['email'];
                    $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $result -> fields['username'];
                    $_SESSION['VERIFIED'] = $result -> fields['verified'];
                    $_SESSION['SGENDER'] = $result -> fields['gender'];
                    $_SESSION['FB'] = "1";

                    $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/$user/picture?type=large";
                    $sourceFilePath = CurlHelper::downloadFile($url, array('followLocation' => true, 'maxRedirs' => 5, ));

                    $theimageinfo = getimagesize($sourceFilePath);
                    $thepp = $_SESSION['USERID'];

                    if ($theimageinfo[2] == 1) {
                        $thepp .= ".gif";
                    } elseif ($theimageinfo[2] == 2) {
                        $thepp .= ".jpg";
                    } elseif ($theimageinfo[2] == 3) {
                        $thepp .= ".png";
                    }

                    $myvideoimgnew = $config['membersprofilepicdir'] . "/" . $thepp;

                    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($sourceFilePath);

                    //on save tel quel
                    $thumb -> save($myvideoimgnew);
                    //on redimensionne la photo
                    $thumb -> resize(100, 100);
                    // save dans le bon rep
                    $tothumbdir = $config['membersprofilepicdir'] . "/thumbs/" . $thepp;
                    $thumb -> save($tothumbdir);

                    if (file_exists($config['membersprofilepicdir'] . "/" . $thepp)) {
                        $query = "UPDATE members SET profilepicture='$thepp' WHERE USERID='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['USERID']) . "'";
                        $conn -> execute($query);
                    } else {
                        $error = "$lang[135]";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => '**APPID**', 'secret' => '**SECRETID**', ));
        $params = array(scope => 'email, user_birthday');

        $loginUrl = $facebook -> getLoginUrl($params);


        if ($_SESSION['language'] == "english") {

            $loginLien_right = "<a href='$loginUrl'><img id='fb_login_image' src='$config[imageurl]/fb_signup_en_right.png' alt='Login Facebook'/></a>";

            $loginLien = "<a href='$loginUrl'><img id='fb_login_image' src='$config[imageurl]/fb_signup_en.png' alt='Login Facebook'/></a>";
        } else {

            $loginLien_right = "<a href='$loginUrl'><img id='fb_login_image' src='$config[imageurl]/fb_signup_fr_right.png' alt='Login Facebook'/></a>";
            $loginLien = "<a href='$loginUrl'><img id='fb_login_image' src='$config[imageurl]/fb_signup_fr.png' alt='Login Facebook'/></a>";
        }


        STemplate::assign('loginFB', $loginLien);
        STemplate::assign('loginFBright', $loginLien_right);

    }
}




?>
```

As I dont have 10 and more reputation I can't post more than 2 hyperlinks so I joined them in a pastebin link

http://pastebin.com/02cm3DjZ

Thanks a lot

Comment: Would I need to replace if (isset($_SESSION['fb_277467322296156_user_id']))
By
 if(isset($_COOKIE['fbsr_277467322296156'])) 
?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual issue is. Are you saying if you login with Facebook, then return to the app, you aren't seeing any user information?

Comment: exactly... user ain't login in....